# Silverstripe all of the page types disappeared

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am running Silverstripe on Windows with MSSQL plugin. Everything worked perfectly until a few days ago when I had to add a new page type. Page type didn't want to appear, so I cleared all of the cache in Silverstripe-cache folder. Suddenly all of the page types were gone. Now I can't add a new page because I can't select it's page type.

I tried updating to the newest version 3.0.5 and also rebuilding with /dev/build. Nothing is working!

Do you have any suggestions for solving this problem.

Comment: was the cache rebuilt once you ran `?flush=1` or `?flush=all`. If you look in your database, you should see the page types in the `SiteTree.ClassName` column enum values, are they there?

Comment: Milion times thank you. Sorry for the late response, but StackOverflow didn't notify me about the comment. The problem was the missing constraint. I had no idea this is what SilverStripe is looking for when showing page types. I had to manually add constraint that included all of the page types and now it works.